# How to access windows binary from Cygwin?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

The path is in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

It's an executable in Windows

```
C:\>dir C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH

01/01/2019  01:33 AM           891,337 ssh.exe
               1 File(s)        891,337 bytes

C:\>C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           destination [command]
```

But not accessable in Cygwin with the same path.

```
[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"
ls: cannot access C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory
```

**Update 1**

```
[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l "C:\WINDOWS\System32\ipconfig.exe"
-rwxr-xr-x 2 user mkpasswd 29184 Apr 12  2018 C:\WINDOWS\System32\ipconfig.exe
[user@cygwin ~]$

[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l "C:\WINDOWS\System32\ipconfig"
-rwxr-xr-x 2 user mkpasswd 29184 Apr 12  2018 C:\WINDOWS\System32\ipconfig
[user@cygwin ~]$

[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/ipconfig
-rwxrwx---+ 2 TrustedInstaller TrustedInstaller 29184 Apr 12  2018 /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/ipconfig
[user@cygwin ~]$

[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/ipconfig.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 2 TrustedInstaller TrustedInstaller 29184 Apr 12  2018 /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/ipconfig.exe
[user@cygwin ~]$
```

I was able to access most Windows binaries using both Windows () & Cygwin (/) format except for `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

```
[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
ls: cannot access /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory
[user@cygwin ~]$

[user@cygwin ~]$ ls -l "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"
ls: cannot access C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory
[user@cygwin ~]$
```

**Update 2**

```
C:\>DIR /s/b C:\ssh.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_openssh-client-components-onecore_<RandomNumber1>_10.0.17134.1_none_<RandomNumber2>\ssh.exe

C:\>
```

Comment: Use the cygwin ssh.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not found. `[user@cygwin ~]$ ssh
-sh: ssh: command not found
[user@cygwin ~]$
`

Answer (score 0):

Change back slashes (`\`) with forward slashes (`/`) and replace drive letter plus colon (`:`) with `/cygdrive/` plus lowercase *drive-letter*. For example:

```
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

Comment: it works with other binaries, but not ssh.exe. I've updated my post

Comment: Please paste `DIR /s/b C:\ssh.exe` output also on your original post.